# How to maintain sessions in java URLConnection?

Tags: java, request, urlconnection

I am trying to login to a website and get page source of a page site after I login to the web site with java URLConnection. The problem I am facing is I can't maintain session so server gives me this warning and doesn't let me to get connected:

> This system requires the use of HTTP cookies to verify authorization information.
>                                        Our system has detected that your browser has disabled HTTP cookies, or does not support them.
>                                        Please refer to the Help page in your browser for more information on how to correctly configure your browser for use with this system.

At first I am trying to send empty cookie to let server to understand I am handling sessions but it doesn't give me session id either.

This is my source code:

```
try {
        // Construct data
        String data = URLEncoder.encode("usr", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("usr", "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("pass", "UTF-8");

        // Send data
        URL url = new URL("https://loginsite.com");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "SESSID=");
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(data);
        wr.flush();

        // Get the response
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        wr.close();
        rd.close();

        String headerName=null;
        for (int i=1; (headerName = conn.getHeaderFieldKey(i))!=null; i++) {
            if (headerName.equals("Set-Cookie")) {
                String cookie = conn.getHeaderField(i);
                System.out.println(cookie.split(";", 2)[0]);
            }
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an HTTP library which handles session management and other details of the HTTP protocol for you, e.g. supports Cookies and things like Keep-Alive, Proxies etc. out of the box. Try [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/)

Comment: upon further research it would appear android is actually recommending the use of HttpUrlConnection, instead of HttpClient.  http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html